# Android: Launching new activity from dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-activity

I'm trying to use a custom dialog to get user input for a title String, and then if the user clicks OK, it will fire up a new Activity (basically a notepad) with that title String as the title. However, when I try to call the method that fires the new activity inside onClick(), it gives me an error.

Here's the code

```
class NewListDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {

        Button search;
        EditText text;

        public NewListDialog(Context context) {
            super(context);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.newlist_dialog);
            search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dialog_confirm);
            text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dialog_editable);
            search.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v == search) {
                String title_name = text.getText().toString();

                       // method for launching new activity
               fireListEdit(title_name);  
            }
        }
```

}

```
void fireListEdit(String title_name) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ListEdit.class);
        i.putExtra(InvenDB.KEY_TITLE, title_name);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
}
```

And I call this dialog with

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case INSERT_ID:
        NewListDialog dialog = new NewListDialog(this);
        dialog.show();
        return true;
    case QUIT_ID:
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}
```

Edit: when I run it on emulator, when I click OK on the custom dialog it just gives me "the application stopped unexpectly" error

EDIT:

This is the logcat, I'm not really sure what they mean :\

01-12 17:39:27.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(426): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jin.inventoryapp/com.jin.inventoryapp.ListEdit}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Comment: You don't tell us what the error is or how you're trying to start your new activity

Comment: Sorry, when I run it on simulator, when I click OK on the custom dialog it just gives me "the application stopped unexpectly" error

Comment: Go to the LogCat in Eclipse to get more information about the error occured. and dont forget to add your activity to manifest file ;)

Comment: Yeah, I added the Activity in the manifest file.

What/where is LogCat? Thanks! Edit: Nevermind, found it on Google, will post once I find the error log

Comment: I just realized that my method for starting new activity is inside parent class (I made it nested, so the Dialog class is within parent class), but it's protected, so the Dialog should still be able to call the method, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell there is a problem with the Adapter (data) part of your application. Whatever Adapter class you used to back your com.jin.inventoryapp.ListEdit, it has a problem accessing the data. i.e. if you are using an array or database to populate your ListView, check there first.

[This](http://grepcode.com/search/usages?id=repository.grepcode.com%24java%24ext@com.google.android%24android@2.3_r1@android%24database@CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException&type=type&k=u) is useful to figure out who is throwing an exception.

Comment: Thanks, that was it, something was wrong with my IDs in ListEdit class, now to figure out that problem...

Comment: Jin, Can you mark your question answered? Btw, a good way to test database issues is to create a unit test inheriting from AndroidTestCase. That way you will get access to activity context, from which you can gain access to the db and test returned Cursor obj.